# Нужно сделать обращение к словарю в списке. api

Tags: python, python-3.x

У меня есть api

```
photo_url = requests.get('https://api.thecatapi.com/v1/images/search').json()
```

Если сделать `print(photo_url)`

То вывод будет: `[{'breeds': [], 'id': 'aqr', 'url': 'https://cdn2.thecatapi.com/images/aqr.jpg', 'width': 480, 'height': 640}]`

мне нужно обратится к url и получить адрес.

Comment: `photo_url[0]["url"]`

Answer (score 0):

Прошу

```
import requests

photo_url = requests.get('https://api.thecatapi.com/v1/images/search').json()[0]
print(photo_url['url'])
```